# Enabling ANSI escape sequences on Windows let disable some Unicode sequences. How to Solve?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, c++17, ansi-escape

I recently enabled ANSI escape sequences on my Windows console using this functions defined in an header `my_windows.h`:

```
#ifndef WINDOWS_HPP
#define WINDOWS_HPP

namespace osm
 {
  extern void enableANSI();
  extern void disableANSI();
 }
```

and implemented in `my_windows.cpp`

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#include "my_windows.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace osm
 {
  #ifdef _WIN32
  #ifndef ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
  #define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING 0x0004
  #endif
  #endif

  #ifdef _WIN32
  static HANDLE stdoutHandle;
  static DWORD outModeInit;
  #endif
  
  void enableANSI()
   {
    #ifdef _WIN32

    DWORD outMode = 0;
    stdoutHandle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    
    if( stdoutHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
     {
      exit( GetLastError() );
     }
    
    if( ! GetConsoleMode( stdoutHandle, &outMode ) )
     {
      exit( GetLastError() );
     }
    
    outModeInit = outMode;
    
    outMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    
    if( ! SetConsoleMode( stdoutHandle, outMode ) )
     {
      exit( GetLastError() );
     }
  
    #endif
   }
  
  void disableANSI()
   {
    std::cout << "\033[0m";
  
    #ifdef _WIN32
    if( ! SetConsoleMode( stdoutHandle, outModeInit ) )
     {
      exit( GetLastError() );
     }
    #endif
   }
 }
```

They are used respectively to enable and disable ANSI escape sequences and work well. The problem is that it seems that the function to enable ANSI at the same time disable some Unicode characters, in particular: `"\u250c", "\u2500", "\u2510", "\u2502", "\u2502", "\u2514", "\u2500", "\u2518"` which if sent to the output stream show strange symbols instead of their corresponding characters. If I don't use the `enableANSI` function the unicode characters works well.

Sorry for the maybe trivial question, but it is the first time I deal with Windows cpp functions.

Thanks.

Comment: You're referring to two completely different things. In a terminal, ANSI escape sequences refers to specific sequences that control the terminal, not character escape sequences and encodings. There are no Unicode terminal escape sequences.

Comment: You can use ANSI escape sequences in a terminal that uses the Unicode encoding - in fact, on Windows, that's the only way. Before the new Windows Terminal introduced on Windows 10 the console didn't support escape sequences. Windows Terminal uses Unicode, including UTF8. You need to enable the correct terminal codepage though. For UTF8, it's 65001. You can do that from the command line with `chcp 65001` or through the *new* Console API calls

Comment: Check [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Googling for VT Sequences avoids the confusion caused by talking about ANSI Escape sequences

Comment: The [Windows Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) blog series explains how the new Console infrastructure works to support UTF8 and VT codes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the fact is that I am on MSYS2 and by default, Unicode characters are displayed correctly, but if I use the previously defined functions to enable ANSI sequences they got disabled for a reason that is not clear to me

Comment: Ok, I've solved! I put this line of code `system( "chcp 65001" );` after using the `enableANSI` function and it works. I'll write it better in a full answer to my question and will mention you. However, thanks a lot @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [PanagiotisKanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) i solved the issue by using the `chcp 65001` command. The problem is that if I am on MSYS2 I am unable to run this command from the shell: therefore I used the `system()` function to call it directly in my code, since my executables run directly on the Windows shell:

```
// code without using ANSI escape sequences...
enableANSI();
// code which uses ANSI escape sequences...
system( "chcp 65001" );
// code which uses ANSI escape sequences and Unicode characters...
```